# Ошибка в функции он-лайн

Tags: php

Делаю такую штуку:

```
$time = time();
$online = $time - (20*60);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE users_come >= $online");
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ){
echo "<br>{$row['username']}"; }
```

Она выводит пользователей он-олайн
но мне выбивает такую ошибку:

*Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:xampphtdocsstyleonline.php on line 20*

Что оно значит и как исправить подскажите пожалуйста !

Comment: А вы уверены что ошибка именно в этом куске кода?

Comment: да, именно в этом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

скорее всего вам не удалось подключится к базе-данных. Либо запрос составлен не верно. Например нету какого то поля или оно называется по другому.

сделайте после

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE users_come >= $online");
var_dump(mysql_error());
```

Comment: ага, спасибо большое=) Так оно и есть =)